# DialogFragment not resizing when keyboard shown

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-view, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to use a `SherlockDialogFragment` to ask some input from the user. Everything works fine on my phone (Galaxy Nexus, 4.2), but on a smaller phone (emulator 2.3.3), when the keyboard shows up, it covers the two buttons of the DialogFragment, like this:

[image: dialog covered by keyboard]

My layout is inside a ScrollView, and I'm changing the softInputMode to `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` on my `onViewCreated`. I also tried `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN`, and it didn't work

**MyCustomDialog.java**

```
public class AddTaskDialog extends SherlockDialogFragment implements OnDateSetListener{
//...
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    }
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        this.inflater =  getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View mainView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(mainView);
        this.taskNote = (EditText) mainView.findViewById(R.id.ET_taskNote);
        this.taskText = (EditText) mainView.findViewById(R.id.ET_taskText);
        this.taskValue = (EditText) mainView.findViewById(R.id.ET_taskValue);
        /*
         * Other stuff
         */
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.new_task, hType.toString()))
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_confirm_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //...
                    }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

And here is my layout:

**custom_dialog.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@color/abs__background_holo_light">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_taskText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/task_text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET_taskText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/create_task_hint"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_taskNote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/task_note"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET_taskNote"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/task_note_hint">

        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/repeat_days"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
        <!-- Day buttons are put here programatically -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, could you help me, and guide me on how to show those buttons? Either to PAN the view or let it resize...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Set the `windowSoftInputMode` property to `adjustNothing` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the activities that use the dialog fragment.

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
...
```

and `onCreateDialog` to hide the soft input:

```
...
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
return dialog;
}
```

FYI: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#ShowOnStart

Comment: Since it was a DialogFragment, it didn't have any associated activity in the manifest, so the first point is useless, but the other one fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more specific about edition of the manifest code.

Comment: Why without `dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);` dialog is not re-sized? This looks like bug.

Answer (score 50):

I just use the following line in my DialogFragment:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

And nothing else, see here full example:

```
    public class TextEditor extends DialogFragment {

    public TextEditor () {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_editor, container);

        //set to adjust screen height automatically, when soft keyboard appears on screen 
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

        //[add more custom code...]
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: For me it was crititcal to call `setSoftInputMode()` from `onCreateView()` and nowhere else, for example calling it from `onCreateDialog()` did not work

Answer (score 11):

Be sure that the layout is inside a scroll view:

```
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  -->your layout here 
</ScrollView>
```

and follow [Dirk comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26434420/1699586):

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_editor, container);

//add this line 
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

      //[add more custom code...]
      return view;
    }
```

Comment: Absolutely the ONLY thing that worked for me when trying to get the `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` behavior.

Comment: Yeah this should be the accepted  answer thanks @Sara

Answer (score 9):

Even though it is a little late for a reply, since the question is in DialogFragment, the following code solves my issue.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    // Setting STYLE_NO_FRAME allows popup dialog fragment to resize after keyboard is shown
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.theme_popupdialog_style);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

    return dialog;
}
```

As for the style theme, I applied the following code

```
/** must put parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog for it to work */
<style name="theme_popupdialog_style" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item .... >...</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 9):

If someone is having similar problem for BottomSheetDialog. This solution works like a charm.

Inside styles:

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item> 
</style>
```

**android:windowIsFloating** should be `false`

**android:windowSoftInputMode** must be `adjustResize`.

```
<style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_corner_dialog</item>
</style>
```

Wrap layout inside NestedScrollView

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <--Rest of the layout-->
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

On some devices this solution wasn't enough. Adding this to code solved my problem completely.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    dialog?.setOnShowListener {
        val dialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
        val bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        bottomSheet?.let { sheet ->
            dialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            sheet.parent.parent.requestLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, after wasting two days on trying different things , you solution worked for me but only first two steps. I did'nt need any nested scroolview

Answer (score 7):

This can also be caused by:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Try to remove it from your theme.

Comment: do you know why is it?

Comment: I think it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, do you know ho to "fix" it with transluent status enabled?

Comment: I had the same issue. I used         <item name="android:statusBarColor">#someTranslucentColor</item> as a workaround. It seems to work fine with fitssystemwindows and stuff

Answer (score 5):

Apart the changes mentioned in other answers also check the **theme** of dialogfragment
From my experiments, "***android:windowIsFloating***" attribute seems to affect how the window reacts to the soft input. 
It you set this to false, the window won't slide up when the keyboard becomes visible.

Comment: This did the magic, after spending so many hours, this answer saved the day!

Answer (score 4):

To work properly with AutoCompleteTextView DialogFragment must not be set as FullScreen.
Instead, you can set width as match_parent in your style.
Below example code:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    dialog?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_filter, container)
}

override fun getTheme(): Int {
    return R.style.AlertDialog_FullWidth
}
```

Styles:

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.8</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/PauseDialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialog.FullWidth" parent="AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and `dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WIndowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);` are the right way of doing this.

BUT. If your view is not resizeable at all, then your buttons in the bottom will still be hidden. In my case, **this hack** was enough:

[image: KEYBOARD HIDDEN]

I set `android:layout_weight` for top views, so that when keyboard opens and dialog is resized — top views would be hidden:
[image: KEYBOARD SHOWN]

Comment: Hi @soshial, I know this is very old but the dialog crushes the content when I try this!

Comment: Yes, content gets minimized — this is the only quick workaround that I found working.

Comment: I'm using the MaterialDialog library ;)

Answer (score -1):

For `DialogFragment`, it seems that applying `SoftInputMode` only works if it setted from inside the `DialogFragment` class, not the caller class:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);    

}
```

Also, for `onStart` method, I added the following to expand dialog layout horizontally:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```