# Keyboard Hides and Covers Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, dialog, resize

I am making an Android app in which I show a Dialog Fragment where users can sumbit text. The problem is that the keyboard shows over the dialog and I couldn't find any way to fix it! I've tried doing the following with no luck:

- Adding the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute in my `AndroidManifest.xml` with multiple values like `"adjustPan|adjustResize"`
- Using `dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);` with `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN`, `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` but that just *crushes* the content of the dialog.
- This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51821469/6766678 where the screenshots are what I want to achieve.

This is what my dialog looks like when the keyboard is open:
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" is not working for you?

Comment: No, I have already tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided using [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)